# Why is this user is missing a particular badge although they have 450 points?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, top-users

I'm wondering if I've stumbled on a bug here.  I noticed recently that I'd achieved the silver badge on "concurrency" on SO.  Yay to me.

> https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1787/concurrency

There are 3 other guys that have done so -- of course Jon is one.  So then I wondered who else is close to their silver for this category and so I go to the top-users page:

> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/concurrency/topusers

I was surprise to see Don Stewart above me at 450 points and yet has not gotten the silver badge for concurrency as far as I can tell.  It's not on his user page or in the concurrency badge page.

Is this a bug or am I not understanding how the badge is calculated?

As always, thanks for SO.  Always a great resource.

Comment: He needs 50 more answers... it's said right there in the badge description page that you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.`

So, they're currently 50 answers short of the 80 for the badge to click in...

Comment: Duh.  Thanks.  Should have realized.  Thanks.